# i'm unable to export table into excel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

i'm using `phpExcel` library for table `export`. i have tried `excelexport` plugin which failed in my case.

when it prints the `output` looks like this

**my jun**k **output**: https://jsfiddle.net/80gzzp4a/

> i'm running the code on server
>    i'm storing the table into

$_SESSION

here is my code

```
<?php

include('../connectmssql.php');
$obj = new SqlDB(); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$filename = 'abc.xlsx';
$table = stripslashes($_SESSION["tableDataToBePrintedNowOnly"]);
require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php'; 
// save $table inside temporary file that will be deleted later
$tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'html');
//$tmpfile = '/tmp/' . rand(0, getrandmax()) . rand(0, getrandmax()) . ".tmp";

file_put_contents($tmpfile, $table);

// insert $table into $objPHPExcel's Active Sheet through $excelHTMLReader
$objPHPExcel     = new PHPExcel();
$excelHTMLReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');
$excelHTMLReader->loadIntoExisting($tmpfile, $objPHPExcel);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('any name you want'); // Change sheet's title if you want

unlink($tmpfile); // delete temporary file because it isn't needed anymore

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); // header for .xlxs file
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename); // specify the download file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
?>
```

**UPDATE 1** :  now i'm getting this `error`

> Notice: Use of undefined constant PHPEXCEL_ROOT - assumed
>   'PHPEXCEL_ROOT' in
>   C:\HostingSpaces\cybrainwebsites\assessment.sahasraadvisoryagency.com\superadmin\Classes\PHPExcel\Autoloader.php
>   on line 73
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_ZipStreamWrapper'
>   not found in
>   C:\HostingSpaces\cybrainwebsites\assessment.sahasraadvisoryagency.com\superadmin\Classes\PHPExcel\Autoloader.php:31
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\HostingSpaces\cybrainwebsites\assessment.sahasraadvisoryagency.com\superadmin\printtable.php(9):
>   require() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\HostingSpaces\cybrainwebsites\assessment.sahasraadvisoryagency.com\superadmin\Classes\PHPExcel\Autoloader.php
>   on line 31

**update 2**:  no error is coming but `excel` will remain blank.

```
if i  echo this line  echo $table = stripslashes($_SESSION["tableDataToBePrintedNowOnly"]);
```

data will come like this: https://jsfiddle.net/4dx9utjc/1/

> if i don't echo then no data

what i'm doing wrong please help me,  thanks in advance!!

Comment: You're running an old version of PHPExcel that has debug statements being displayed. Update to a newer version, or comment out those echos from the HTML Reader

Comment: sir @mark Baker, i'm getting this error now i,e update 1

Comment: What version are you running now? Which branch did you pull from github?

Comment: i'm using `version 1.8.0` from here https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: @sir, @mark Baker please look at my `update 2`

Comment: __Please stop using the old, dead codeplex site__; it's been over 4½ years since we moved to [github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) (we moved on 2012-06-19), and I really wish codeplex would let us delete the site completely.... and it doesn't seem to matter that we have messages on the front page telling people to use github instead, nobody ever seems to bother reading them.

Comment: thank you sir for your support.  now i have solved my problem with a `javascript` plugin called `tableexport.js`.     thanks once again for your precious time.